# MS Excel - IF then with conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have another tricky Excel IF-Then formula that I need but I can’t figure out how to search for a solution online without knowing the correct terms to use.

What I’m trying to do is generate a result based off of 4 multiple options. This is similar to calculating someone's commission based on what price range they sell an item for.

> Result =$1 for an item selling for $0-10.00
>
> Result =$2 for an item selling between $10.01-12.50
>
> Result =$3 for an item selling between $12.51-15.00
>
> Result =$4 for an item selling $15.01 and up

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Why not use vlookup() and a data table.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the selling price is in A2. We are starting from the bottom range of your pricing and using nested IF's to figure out which bucket the selling price is in.  We will check if it is <= 10, if so then the result will be 1, if not then we will check if it is <= 12.50, if so then the result will be 2.. etc.  Formula shown below.

```
=if(a2<=10,1,if(a2<=12.50,2,if(a2<=15,3,4)))
```

Comment: SO is note made to provide solutions without any context, as this does not help other people. Try to provide some level of generality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a capsuled if clause.

If is build up as following:

```
=if(condition, value if true, value if false)
```

Capsuled:

```
=if(condition1, value if true, if(condition2, value is true, if(...)))
```

The condition needs to resolve in a `True/False` Statement. For your case:

```
=if(price <= upperBound AND  price >= lowerBound, commision, if(...))
```

If you arrange the conditions in the right order (from high to low) you do only need to type one bound per condition.

```
=if(price > 15, highestCommision, if(price > secondBound, Commision2, if(...)))
```

RESULT:

```
=if(A1 > 15, 4, if( A1 > 12.5, 3, if( A1 > 10, 2, 1 )))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) in its relative form.  This will find where the number fits and return the relative location as a Long:

```
=MATCH(A1,{0,10.01,12.51,15.01})
```

[image]

---

Or if you have Office 365 Excel you can use [IFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45):

```
=IFS(A1<=10,1,A1<=12.5,2,A1<=15,3,A1>15,4)
```

Comment: This is actually really cool and I have never seen `match` used like this, but you should explain about the `match type` and that it is not returning a mapped value, but rather the indices of the match. Therefore the solution only holds for linearly scaleable and equaly sized buckets

Comment: Why when Microsoft on their own web page discusses this in more detail than I could.  As to the output, you are correct it only works for 1,2,3,4 but we could easily add an INDEX or CHOOSE to return a non ascending linear return.  And I did say relative location.

Answer (score 1):

... or if the selling price was in A3,

=1+(a3>10)+(a3>12.5)+(a3>15)

A boolean TRUE is resolved as 1 when used in a maths operation like addition.

Comment: 5 characters shorter than mine,but mine becomes shorter the more that is added. 8P

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety here is a version with vlookup:

```
VLOOKUP(E4,B3:C6,2,1)
```

and the table I used:
[image]
Corrected after Scott's comment and Jeeped's - cheers guys...

Comment: @ScottCraner so right - edited and seems to be fine now.

Comment: Just for giggles, here is your formula "Hard Coded" just in case the OP does not want a separate table: `=VLOOKUP(E4,{0,1;10.01,2;12.51,3;15.01,4},2,TRUE)`